# asp.net C# windows authentication iss config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I'm developing a webpage where a need to know the users windows authentication values, more precisely the name.

Others developments have been done with this kind of authentication but sadly for me their creators are long gone and i have no contact or documentation.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and i'm accessing a webservice that is in a remote server. The server is a windows server 2008 r2 standard and is using ISS version 7.5.

Since i have the source code of the other developments what i did was copy paste and was working fine when i was calling the webservice that was in my machine (localhost).
The code is the following:

```
//1st way
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
string strUser = wp.Identity.Name;//ALWAYS GET NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
//2nd way
WindowsIdentity winId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(winId);
string user = winPrincipal.Identity.Name;//ALWAYS GET NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
//3rd way
IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
string userstr = wi.Name; //ALWAYS GET string empty 

btn_select.Text = userstr;
btn_cancelar.Text = strUser;
btn_gravar.Text = user;
```

As you can see i have here 3 ways to get the same and in a sad manner show my user's name.
As for my web.config i have:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

In the IIS manager i have tried lots of combination of enable and disable between Anonymous Authentication, ASP.NET Impersonation, Basic Authentication, Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication.

Can please someone help me??

NOTE: The respective values i get from each try are in the code

Comment: The one that needs to get the current user's name is the web application or the remote web service? If it's the web application, I believe you should just enable Windows Integrated Authentication, disable Anonymous access, and use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Comment: Pablo -> I have done as you said but that way i get asked for credentials. I wish for my web application to get the user's machine credentials (Name), since it is an internal development. The user logs in in his/her machine with name x and goes to my application and that name x i what i want. Thanks for helping me by the way.

Comment: @user1566209: what is the url that you are going to? If it has a . in it, your browser will not pass the credentials to the web server.

Comment: You can try using current thread identity: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity

Comment: adrianbanks -> a .? it has cause im accessing through the ip so i have xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/rest_of_url. Is that the problem?

Comment: Most likely. If there is a . present in the url, browsers switch from the intranet zone to the internet zone (this is the IE terms, not sure if other browsers refer to them the same but they certainly work the same). As you are no longer in the intranet zone, no credentials are passed along with requests, even if integrated Windows authentication is turned on. You should be able to turn basic authentication on as well for testing and it should work, but it _will_ prompt for credentials.

Comment: I agree with adrianbanks. The problem with going to a site by IP is that Windows can only automatically determine that an IP is on your LAN if it's on the same subnet as your machine or if certain proxy behaviors are configured. You'll need to manually add the site to your Local Intranet settings in IE.

Comment: For my problem the solution i got was to set Asp.net impersonation to enabled and windows authentication enabled, this in the IIS, leaving everything disabled. For me this worked with the code of the 2nd way (Windows.Identity && Windows.Principal) although i got prompted for the user and password, this only happened the first. time